# Why when i'm trying to perform login i don't get the html of the next page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-scraping

I have a site that i need to **scrape** but i need to pass a login first, something is wrong with the login because i'm not getting the data i need.

My code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://online.fibi.co.il/MatafLoginService/MatafLoginServlet? 
bankId=FIBIPORTAL&site=Private&KODSAFA=HE'

 payload = {
     'username': 'myUserName',
     'password': 'myPassword'
 }

 requestedUrl = 'https://online.fibi.co.il/wps/myportal/FibiMenu/Online'

 with requests.Session() as session:
     post = session.post(url, data=payload)
     r = session.get(requestedUrl)
     print(post.status_code)
     print(r.status_code)
     print(r.text)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a GET of the login page before doing the POST - this often loads the session with cookies needed for the login.

Comment: Hi, tried it right now but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe the login isn't actually working. In that case your best bet is to trace a browser login and retrieval of the page, using e.g. Telerik Fiddler (Windows) or mitm (Linux), then replicate the headers/parameters in your python code.